# Vue child component leave transition callback not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, gsap

I defined a `Parent` component which have a `Child` component, both components have dynamic transitions with leave callbacks defined as `outro`, the problem is that when `Parent` component gets destroyed its `outro` method works fine but its `Child` component `outro` method never gets fired. Is there anyway to accomplish this and keep `Child` component reusable and decoupled? [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aguerrero_g87/uz3srhx9/).

App template:

```
<div id="app">
  <parent v-if="showContainer"></parent>
  <button @click="showContainer = !showContainer">
    Toggle Container
  </button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// ISSUE:
// 1. Parent removes child component in its `outro` method
// 2. Child `outro` method never gets called

var Child = {
    template: `
    <transition
        :css="false"
        appear
        @appear="intro"
        @enter="intro"
        @leave="outro"
    >
        <div class="Child"></div>
    </transition>`,
    methods: {
        intro: function (el, done) {
            TweenLite.fromTo(el, 0.5,
                { y: '100%' },
                { y: '0%', delay: 0.5, onComplete: done })
        },
        outro: function (el, done) {
            // 2 <===
            TweenLite.to(el, 0.5,
                { y: '100%', onComplete: done })
        },
    },
}

var Parent = {
    template: `
    <transition
        :css="false"
        appear
        @appear="intro"
        @enter="intro"
        @leave="outro"
    >
        <div class="Parent">
            <div ref="inner" class="Parent__inner"></div>
            <child v-if="showChild"></child>
        </div>
    </transition>`,
    components: {
        Child: Child,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            showChild: true,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        intro: function (el, done) {
            TweenLite.fromTo(this.$refs.inner, 0.5,
                { y: '100%' },
                { y: '0%', delay: 0.25, onComplete: done })
        },
        outro: function (el, done) {
            // 1 <===
            // Setting `showChild` to `false` should remove Child component
            // and trigger its `outro` method ¿?
            this.showChild = false
            TweenLite.to(this.$refs.inner, 0.5,
                { y: '100%', delay: 0.25, onComplete: done })
        },
    },
}

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            showContainer: true,
        }
    },
    components: {
        Parent: Parent,
    },
})
```

Comment: please, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see corrected [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/simati/rfLn70ck/)

1. Use `v-show` directive. See compare [v-if vs f-show](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show)

   ```
   <parent v-show="showContainer"></parent>
   ```
2. child elements need self-controller and binding with properties

- add `v-if="showChild"` in `<div class="Child"></div>`
- create `props` in `child`

  > props: {
  > showChild: {
  > type: Boolean,
  > default: true
  > }
  > },
- binding `props` in `parent`

  > ```
  > <child :showChild="showChild"></child>
  > ```

Comment: Oh! you're right, using `v-show` on the `Parent` worked great, I actually can skip the second step (use props on the `Child` component) and just use `v-show` or `v-if`, that way my `Child` components keeps unaltered. [This demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/aguerrero_g87/vek8b0dc/) is how I use it at the end. Thanks.

Comment: glad to help) your final version better.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's not possible this way.
Even when using CSS transitions, the parent still need to control the child's transition out.
We'd need a disappear prop on Transition component :p

Maybe you won't love this solution but, in the parent's outro, you can call `this.$refs.child.outro(this.$refs.child.$el)`